# How to I get a window in VMWare Fusion 2.06 on a second monitor in Unity mode?

Tags: mouse, vmware-fusion, vmware-unity

I have VMware Fusion 2.06 on my MacBook Pro running 10.6.1. When I try to drag a window (like Internet Explorer) while in Unity mode to my secondary monitor, it works until my mouse hits the second screen.  At that point the window begins sliding out from under my mouse and the mouse slows down (not keeping up with my drag).  I also noticed today when I look at the VMware library window that the preview doesn't show the background matching up:

[image]

I think the mouse is confused as to where it is on the screen because when I try to click on the window that is partially on the secondary monitor, it seems to click somewhere else on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t. VMware 2.x doesn’t support that. VMware 3.0 does, but not without bugs. When running full screen in VMware 3.0 and having more than one display, occasionally, the mouse pointer will go crazy and you click on one screen and nothing seems to happen. But the click is actually taking place in the **other** screen. It’s weird. It happens, and the only “fix” i’ve found so far is to go to display preferences in windows and try to “move” the screen a little bit. Going back and forth full screen/window also fixes it.

I’ve filed a bug.

Parallels 5 **doesn’t have this bug**. Coherence works faster than Unity in my preliminary “less than two weeks” tests.

Comment: Thanks, that has been my conclusion as well.  I like the look of VMWare, but Parallels seemed to perform much faster and I didn't have this mouse problem.